# select all from table where imgid is max in every projid

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM projimg WHERE imgid = ( SELECT MAX( imgid ) FROM projimg )
```

I know the query above will just return 1 value as i try it.

I wanted to get all the max imgid in every projid..

```
imgid | projid |
  1       1
  2       1
  3       2
  4       2
  5       4
  6       4
```

e.g for

projid = 1, i get imgid = 2
projid = 2, i get imgid = 4
projid = 4, i get imgid = 6
and so on...

the result is like below:

```
imgid  | projid
  2        1
  4        2
  6        4
```

Comment: Off the top of my head have you tried using `GROUP BY`? i.e. grouping on projid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM projimg 
WHERE imgid IN ( 
    SELECT MAX( imgid ) 
    FROM projimg 
    group  by projid)
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4f71/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT projid, MAX( imgid ) as imgid
  FROM projimg 
 group by projid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT projid, MAX(imgid) as finalResult
 FROM projimg 
 GROUP BY projid
```